# qt how to link win32 libraries

Tags: qt, winapi

I am using QT Creator 2.4.1. I want to make a network utility. I am using windows function:
GetAdaptersInfo().

This requires iphlpapi.lib to be linked.

To link the libraries I tried to add following argument in **Projects->Build-Setup->Additional Arguments** :

LIBS += -liphlpapi

or

win32:LIBS += -liphlpapi

or

LIBS += iphlpapi.lib

Without any success. I tried to give full path too. Can anyone tell me whats the correct way of linking?

Comment: I don't know, but how about [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html)? And use search before asking (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674254/linking-win32-dll-in-qt?rq=1), it there for a reason

Comment: @elmigranto Read and understand before commenting (especially when criticizing). Your reference link is not at all helpful/relevant. And yes I searched before I posted the question.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong, sorry. But that's not the only similar question. Anyway, try adding those lines in .pro file, clean project, run qmake and rebuild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

1. Add `win32:LIBS += -lIphlpapi` in your `.pro` file;
2. clean (*optional?*);
3. run `qmake`;
4. build.